# Two tables match on JOIN condition. First table has no records

Tags: sql

How can I find the records in one table for which there are no records in a second table that match based on a join condition?

For example, given the two tables:

### Titles

TitleID, ArtistID, Title, StudioID, Genre

### Artists

ArtistID, ArtistName, City, Region, Country

How can I find the records in one table for which there are no records in a second table that match based on a join condition?

Or how would I modify these tables to conform to my question (above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Titles t 
LEFT JOIN Artists a ON t.ArtistsID = a.ArtistsID
WHERE a.ArtistID IS NULL
```